# EhCache terracottaConfig url in https

Tags: https, ehcache, terracotta

Can I work with secured environments (eg. HTTPS) using Terracota server Arrays ?

I 've tried to configure ehcache.xml file like this:

```
<terracottaConfig rejoin="true" url="https://localhost:9510,https://localhost:9511"/>
```

But it remains in error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI can't be null.
at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:116) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:841) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1177) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
at com.tc.config.schema.setup.sources.ServerConfigurationSource.getInputStream(ServerConfigurationSource.java:42) ~[na:na]
at com.tc.config.schema.setup.StandardXMLFileConfigurationCreator.trySource(StandardXMLFileConfigurationCreator.java:343) ~[na:na]
at com.tc.config.schema.setup.StandardXMLFileConfigurationCreator.getConfigDataSourceStrean(StandardXMLFileConfigurationCreator.java:289) ~[na:na]
at com.tc.config.schema.setup.StandardXMLFileConfigurationCreator.loadConfigDataFromSources(StandardXMLFileConfigurationCreator.java:222) ~[na:na]
at com.tc.config.schema.setup.StandardXMLFileConfigurationCreator.loadConfigAndSetIntoRepositories(StandardXMLFileConfigurationCreator.java:120) ~[na:na]
at com.tc.config.schema.setup.StandardXMLFileConfigurationCreator.createConfigurationIntoRepositories(StandardXMLFileConfigurationCreator.java:102) ~[na:na]
at com.terracotta.express.StandaloneL1Boot.resolveEmbedded(StandaloneL1Boot.java:177) ~[terracotta-toolkit-1.5-runtime-4.2.0.jar:na]
at com.terracotta.express.StandaloneL1Boot.resolveConfig(StandaloneL1Boot.java:122) ~[terracotta-toolkit-1.5-runtime-4.2.0.jar:na]
... 106 common frames omitted
```

If it is possible what is the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put Terracotta doesn't support cluster communication over SSL currently. If you are using the commercial edition you have an additional layer of security because a client won't be able to connect to the cluster if it doesn't have the correct license key. Apart from that you can use firewall rules to restrict access.

Comment: Thanks in advance, that's it. I 've posted in Ehcache forum http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/7098.page#35341 and they confirmed that.

Comment: From release Terracotta 3.7 they support https connections.